# An abstract definition of the cotangent space to a smooth manifold.

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I need a book introducing the cotangent space to smooth manifolds in the most abstract way. So $T^\ast_p M$ by this point of view should be the quotient ring $I/I^2$ where $I=\{[f]\in C^{\infty}_p(M)\,:\, [f(p)]=0\}$. I have just seen Lee's book and Tu's book, but both present the cotangent space via derivations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you will find a _book_ with that definition, but you might like to look at §5.3 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0023v4.pdf).

Comment: What about GTM 94, Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups, by Frank W. Warner?